# Parse Datetime to JAVA Date

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, datetime

im getting the SQL Server datetime (1 Jan 2013) form the `SqlRowSet` like

```
while (rs.next()) {
 myBean.setDateProp(rs.getString(4));
}
```

the type of `myBean` `DateProp` is `java.util.Date`, is there a way to convert `(1 Jan 2013)` to java Date representation.

i have tried the following code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date=new Date();        
    try {
        date = sdf.parse("1 Jan 2013");           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

and i get the `ParseException`

> SEVERE: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1 Jan 2013"

any directions...

Comment: _i have tried the following code_ what happened after? have you got any exception?

Comment: Why are you using rs.getString() instead of rs.getDate() ?

Comment: Why are you using the format `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS` when your date string looks like `1 Jan 2013`? It's obvious that the format of the string isn't what you're using.

Comment: @PradeepSimha i get the `ParseException`

Comment: @Charlie i tried that but the format in SQL server db is DateTime so it throws an exception stating no date was found

Comment: @dakait - then did you try rs.getTimestamp() instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this -

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
Date date=new Date();        
try {
    date = sdf.parse("1 Jan 2013");           
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: that almost worked the parsing is done ok but when it is converted to java date it shows me `Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 PKT 2013`

Comment: dont print `java.util.Date` object. print formatted string. lyk - `System.out.println(sdf.format(date));`

Comment: im printing the formatted string and its printing fine but then i have to assign the value to date property of my model ...

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
while (rs.next()) {
 myBean.setDateProp(rs.getDate(4));
}
```

Comment: i tried that but the db server format is datetime so it give me the error that no date was found at index 4

Comment: Sounds suspicious. Anyway, try rs.getTimestamp(4) then.

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws ParseException {

        String dateString = "1 Jan 2013";
        String dateString2 = "11 Jan 2013";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy");


        sdf.parse(dateString);
        sdf.parse(dateString2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your Date formatter string to

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
```

as your date string is in this format