# Remove the seconds and zone info from date JAVA

Tags: java, datetime

i had an issue converting between SQL server's datetime to java's `java.util.date` which has been resolved [Parse Datetime to JAVA Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967635/parse-datetime-to-java-date) but now the issue is my `datetime` (01 Jan 2013) is converted to `Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 PKT 2013` i want it to be like `01 Jan 2013` is it possible or i had to use the strings...
i tried the [JODA time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) but the issue remains the same. please guide me through the correct path

EDIT:

i have `datetime` format in the SQL server db as `dd MMM yyyy` e.g `01 Jan 2013` i had to get the value from the `SqlRowSet` like `rs.getString(4)` now to convert the datetime string which i acquired from the DB to `java.util.date` that i did by using the guidelines in the question mentioned above, but the problem is it adds the additional info of zone and secods like

> 01 Jan 2013   SQL Server Format datetime
>
> Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 PKT 2013 java.util.date format

**what i want is the `java.util.date` to be like `01 Jan 2013`**

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to output your java.lang.Date instance as a String into a file, to the screen, or wahtever in the specified format?

Comment: did't understood  your question.put here your datetime sql server conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `java.util.Date` is internally represented by a number (a `long`), not by fields for day, month, hour, etc... You obtain those by formating this number with a `SimpleDateFormat`. The string you are getting now is a default representation obtained by using `Date.toString()`. If you want it formatted differently, use the `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html will do the job.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd MMM yyyy" );
System.out.println( sdf.format( date ) );
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html can also be used as long as your desired format matches a specific locale.

Here an example that comes close to what you want:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance( DateFormat.LONG, Locale.UK );
System.out.println( df.format( date ) );
```

EDIT: And in order to get the date from the rowset just call

```
Date date = rs.getDate(4);
```

and it will return the date object just as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

In my view betetr use, Joda Time API for easy manipulation of date time field. This API would be very useful for this. Use Date Time formatter or simple date time formatter class in `java.util.Date`package. This would be more helpful for getting the desired result for you.

Answer (score 0):

@Jakub has rightly mentioned. You can do it easily using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

```
java.util.Date today=new java.util.Date();
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy"); 
System.out.println(format.format(today));
```

I have used it to format today's date. You can retrieve date from the database and to in the similar way. But remember if you use `rs.getDate()` it will return you `java.sql.Date`. Accordingly you can proceed.